# How to create a template-expanding directive for multiple blocks of code that only differ from each other in their ng-repeat?

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a piece of code that I want to use in other HTML pages. I'm talking about the following code:

```
<h5>Brand</h5>
<div>
  <div ng-repeat="brand in store.brands.tops">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-true-value="'{{brand}}'" ng-model="selectedBrands[$index]"/>
      {{brand}}
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've placed the above code in a separate HTML file and made a directive for it, so I can use it in my other HTML pages. The code for that looks like this:

```
angular.module('store').directive('brandCheckboxes', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'templates/brand-checkboxes.html',
  };
});
```

However, the code in the template has to look slightly different when I want to use it in another HTML page. Only a part of the ng-repeat has to change, as can be seen below:

```
<h5>Brand</h5>
<div>
  <div ng-repeat="brand in store.brands.bottoms">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-true-value="'{{brand}}'" ng-model="selectedBrands[$index]"/>
      {{brand}}
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to pass an argument into the directive and that the ng-repeat gets changed depending on what argument gets passed in? So that `<brand-checkboxes category="tops"></brand-checkboxes>` generates the first code block and `<brand-checkboxes category="bottoms"></brand-checkboxes>` generates the latter one.

Comment: What about components? you can define bindings: { list: '=' } and uses ng-repeat="brand in $ctrl.list" at template

Comment: @Joazito Polo Where do I have to assign the list?

Answer (score 0):

I would have the directive take in a list something like

```
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'templates/brand-checkboxes.html',
    scope: {
            list: '=',
            ngModel: '='
        }
  };
```

and in the html for the directive tag

```
<brand-checkboxes list="somearray" ng-model="someVar"></brand-checkboxes>
```

then in your directive html would be:

```
<h5>Brand</h5>
<div>
  <div ng-repeat="brand in list">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-true-value="'{{brand}}'" ng-model="ngModel"/>
      {{brand}}
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

This way you can just pass the list that you want to repeat to the directive.

Comment: This partially works. The brand names do get displayed correctly if I change the list name. This is exactly what I want. However, the ng-model part doesn't work anymore. When I click a checkbox it doesn't get added to the selectedBrands array anymore. Do you have any idea how to solve that?

Comment: @Geronimo ah, I missed that. You can pass a ng-model through the directive. I have changed the answer to reflect this.

Comment: This unfortunately didn't fix the problem. The selectedBrands array I use is initialized in a controller I made. Also, the ng-model worked correctly in the original version of my code.